# Sitecore - Analyze ribbon > Attributes dialog is empty for Campaigns/Goals/Attributes tabs

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1, sitecore-xdb

Version- Sitecore 8.1 update 1.

I am trying to tag a media item for Page Download Event.
When I try follow the steps

My Attributes dialog shows no events to select from.
[Events Listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWhtF.jpg)
[Attributes Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1BQb.jpg)

Can Anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was that the analytics were disabled...but then you shouldn't even be able to open the Attributes popup.

Are you logged in as an Sitecore Administrator or another user? Perhaps the user role is not able to set any goals/events.

Have you checked the error log? Perhaps it can help with narrowing down this problem.

Comment: This has been resolved. The issue was we needed to add workflow to the Download event in the page events section [/sitecore/system/Settings/Analytics/Page Events]. Thanks for replying.